# Intuition for group property of the flow of differential equations

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, differential-equations

Consider the IVP
$$\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}x' &= f(t, x), \\
x(0) &= x_0,
\end{aligned}\right.$$
with complete flow $\phi(t, x_0)$. If $f$ is smooth, then the flow has the group property, namely
$$\forall s, t \in \mathbb{R}: \phi(t + s, x) = \phi(t, \phi(s, x)).$$
**Interpretation:** Consider a particle in (say) $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose motion is governed by the differential equation. Let $x_2 = \phi(t + s, x_0).$ In both of these scenarios, you get up at the same point $x_2$:

*Scenario 1:* Start at point $x_0$ and time $ = 0$, and let time flow until $t + s$.

*Scenario 2:* Start at point $x_1 := \phi(s, x_0):= x_1$, reset time $ = 0$, and then let time flow until $t$.

**Question:** The fact that the group property holds is completely magical to me. Is there any intuition for why it's true?

What's even more troubling is this: let's compute the derivative of motion for the particle at point $x_1$ in both scenarios.

*Scenario 1:* $\phi'(s, x_0) = f(s, \phi(s, x_0)) = f(s, x_1).$

*Scenario 2:* $\phi'(0, x_1) = f(0, \phi(0, x_1)) = f(0, x_1).$

In fact, we can say something stronger. The points $x$ and $\phi(s, x)$ have the same orbit until $\phi$.

I really don't see why why $f(s, x_1)$ and $f(0, x_1)$ have to be in the same direction for all $s$. In fact they really don't, so there must be something wrong with my logic above.

Comment: This question seems to be more suitable to [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @NíckolasAlves I would think that if I asked about proofs, it would be more suitable for MSE. But I am asking for intuition about math that describes a physical process, so I thought it would be well-suited here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the group property is false in the considered case. It holds, provided the solutions are complete, when $f$ does not depend on time explicitly, i.e., for autonomous systems.